# PHP Memory Management - Variables within Loops

Tags: php, loops, variables, memory

Does PHP perform wise memory management in regards to variables within loops?

For example, would memory allocation be performed for the following example, beyond the first iteration?

```
foreach ($items as $item) { $item_found = true; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory for variables `$items`, `$item` and `$item_found` will be allocated once (on **first** iteration only). By default, PHP allocates memory for variables if it encounters new ones.

Read about [GC](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) and this question: [How does PHP assign and free memory for variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971090/how-does-php-assign-and-free-memory-for-variables). It should give you some information about PHP memory management. Also note that PHP uses ["*copy-on-write*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) scheme.